# Google Actions not supported for English(Ireland) language

Tags: localization, actions-on-google

I'm developing an Action on Google for the Irish market and I've noticed that my actions aren't available if the language in my account settings is set to English (Ireland), I get a message saying, "<> is not available for your country or language". Would anybody know how solve this issue (other than changing my language settings to English UK or US)? Ideally, I'd like to change some setting in my action so that it will be available no matter what the language selected is and restrict the access only by country.

Answer (score 2):

You can localize your Actions for the Google Assistant to provide customized experiences for different languages and locales that users can set on their devices. Locale is the combination of a language and region, in your case, English (Ireland). Actions on Google can currently be localized to one of the following English locales: USA (`en-US`), UK (`en-GB`), Australia (`en-AU`), Canada (`en-CA`), and a few others. Ireland (`en-IE`) is not one of them, unfortunately.

References: https://developers.google.com/actions/localization/ 
https://developers.google.com/actions/localization/languages-locales

Comment: What if I don't want my action to be localised by language but only by region? Is there any way to do that?

Comment: The actions console is pretty unclear about this. They don't really recognise that regions might need/want localisation. It's even worse when trying to target English users in India, for example.