# Custom Action - Sorry {action name} isn't available or set up for your language or country

Tags: actions-on-google

I have been directed here by Google after raising a ticket with them.

I have a custom action that is saying to some users "Sorry, {action name} isn't available or set up for your language or country." even though the action is available to the users language and country. The user is able to use other similar custom actions without issue and I'm at loss to understand what the problem may be and Google are unable to help further.

I have double checked and all countries are checked in the console and the users devices is set to English (and English is the only locale set for the action.

I'm not sure what else I can do to troubleshoot the problem.

I suspect this will end up being related to this question : [Google Actions not supported for English(Ireland) language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52822112/google-actions-not-supported-for-englishireland-language)

Any pointers would be helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, shortly after posting this I found out what is likely to be the issue and it is indeed related to the link in my question. Will leave this here in case it helps others.

So it would appear that even though having the custom action set to 'English' if the user has their language set to 'English - Ireland' it will not work, but in the action console, there is no ability to add an English (Irish) locale!

So basically, users from Ireland cannot user the custom action.

If anyone knows a solution (other than telling users to change their language), please do let me know!

What I do not understand is how they have other actions that work. Could this be that they are not custom actions?

Comment: Is 'English - Ireland' the language set in the Assistant app? Is there another Action that you see which works in the English/Ireland locale?

Comment: @NickFelker I do not have access to the users app (or access to the user directly unfortunately). I am assuming they have it set to England (Ireland) as I replicated the behaviour by setting mine to that. Wha tI am failing to understand is how they have other actions working and why (oh why) do Google separate Ireland as a language, but then not have it in the console as a locale?? If I find out more info I will update. Thanks.

Comment: Where did you change the language? Is that in the phone settings or the Assistant app settings?

Comment: In the assistant app settings

Comment: I've changed my Assistant language to exclusively English (Ireland) and I've had no issue opening actions. Is your Action public that I can try to open it?

Comment: @NickFelker thanks for your reply. Yes, it is tinyurl.com/29da3srp Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately even with my locale set exclusively to English (Ireland) I am able to open the action and play music.

Comment: @NickFelker thanks for your reply and trying, appreciated. Very strange. I am able to 100% reproduce the issue, as can the user. On the Google Home app, if I go to ‘Assistant Settings’ and then ‘Languages’ and change the language from ‘English – (United Kingdom)’ to ‘English (Ireland)’ it brings up the issue mentioned. Change back to ‘English (United Kingdom)’ and the action works fine.  Google also replied today saying that they were able to change the language to English - (Ireland) and it also worked for them. At this stage, not sure what is happening. Thanks for helping.

Comment: I have a very similar problem but for users in Brazil. Our action supports the English and the Portuguese language. One user in Brazil tried to open the app on his iPhone (not sure if this is part of the problem) which is set up with the English language. The action wont open. But when he switches the language of the assistant app to Portuguese, the action starts working as expected. It seems to be related to the combination of country and language, not just to the language. Did you, @omega1, find a solution or workaround for this yet?

Comment: Just to confirm, in the assistant app from the user from Brazil it is written that it uses the languages set above (English (US)) AND the device language 'English (Brazil)' which obviously does not exist...